# Jenkins and PostgreSQL is consuming a lot of memory

Tags: postgresql, jenkins

We have a Data ware house server running on Debian linux ,We are using PostgreSQL , Jenkins and Python.

It's been few day the memory of the CPU is consuming  a lot by jenkins and Postgres.tried to find and check all the ways from google but the issue is still there.

**Anyone can give me a lead on how to reduce this memory consumption,It will be very helpful.**

below is the output from **free -m**

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          63805        9152         429       16780       54223       37166
Swap:             0           0           0
```

**below is the postgresql.conf file**
[image]
**Below is the System configurations,**

[image]

**Results from htop**
[image]

Comment: Plain text files shouldn't be show as screen shots, but as formatted text.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm incrementally updating a table with "Select * on conflict(order_id) do
UPDATE ...."but the size of the table is 27GB even it contains only few records, and there was a vacuum job running on this table which cause CPU to utilised full.Any way we can reduce it's size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't post text as images. It is hard to read and process.

I don't see your problem.

Your machine has 64 GB RAM, 16 GB are used for PostgreSQL shared memory like you configured, 9 GB are private memory used by processes, and 37 GB are free (the `available` entry).

Linux uses available memory for the file system cache, which boosts PostgreSQL performance. The low value for `free` just means that the cache is in use.

Comment: Sure, Will take care of next time regarding the posting of images.But the CPU was also very high and when we checked found that an AUTO VACUUM Job on a particular table was running a lot of time,Can we change the AUTO VACUUM job to use a certain % of CPU or turn it off?

Comment: That is a different question. You should tune your statements. If you turn off autovacuum, your database will break. Never, ever do that. You should reduce `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay` so that autovacuum consumes even more CPU (and is done faster, which is the goal).

Answer (score 0):

For Jenkins, run it with these JAVA Options

```
JAVA_OPTS=-Xms200m -Xmx300m -XX:PermSize=68m -XX:MaxPermSize=100m
```

For postgres, start it with option

```
-c shared_buffers=256MB
```

These values are the one I use on a small homelab of 8GB memory, you might want to increase these to match your hardware

Comment: What is this option in JENKINS JAVA_OPTS=-Xms200m -Xmx300m -XX:PermSize=68m -XX:MaxPermSize=100m
 ?

Comment: Configured the PostgreSQL based on the suggestions from https://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/#/

Comment: It is heap settings for the JVM. I dont find the article I used at the time I found these but here is a good one https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/11/21/gc-tuning/